# how can i create an if else statement in my navigation bar?

Tags: php

I tried to create an if else statement but its not reading the statement. please how do i make an if else statement?
Here is my navigation Bar:

```
<div id="NavBar">
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) && isset($_SESSION['Voting Status'])=='b'):?>

                <li> <a href="Voted User.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['Username'];?></a></li>
                <li> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                 <?php
                elseif(isset($_SESSION['Username']) && isset($_SESSION['Voting Status'])=='a'):?>

                <li> <a href="Voters Account.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['Username'];?></a></li>
                <li> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
               <?php

                else:?>

                <li><a href="Login2.php">Student Login</a></li>
                <?php
                endif;

                ?>
            <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['Voting Status'])=='b'`? `isset()` returns a **boolean**, it can't be evaluated to a string.

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['x'])=='y'` that's a false positive. You need to break those up.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` returns a boolean ( `true` / `false` ).

You can not combine it with another value like you currently do. `isset(a) == 'b'` will not work like you expect it do.

You need to include the comparison after the `isset` check. Like so:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Username']) and isset($_SESSION['Voting Status']) and $_SESSION['Voting Status'] == 'b'):?>
```